# Configuring Spring DataSource JNDI remote JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, datasource, jndi

I want to local remote DataSource in Spring through JNDI on JBoss 7.1.1 server

Here is my config

**datasource-ds.xml** in WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/DBTest"
        pool-name="dbtest-pool" enabled="true"
        use-java-context="true" jta="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <!-- <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>  -->
        <pool>  
            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>  
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>  
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>root</user-name>
            <password>root</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- Create DataSource Bean -->

<bean id="sampleDataSource"     class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/DBTest" />
</bean>

<bean id="sampleHibernateSessionFactory"
    class="com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortletHibernateConfiguration">
   <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="sampleDataSource" />
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sampeSessionFactory" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryImpl"
lazy-init="true">
    <property name="sessionFactoryImplementor">
        <ref bean="sampleHibernateSessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sampleTransactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="sampleDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sampleHibernateSessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DBTest -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.DBTest
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:123)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:214)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryB
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the configuration.
Thank a lot

Comment: What if you try to put your datasource inside datasources context - java: jboss/datasources/DBTest? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration

Comment: Do you want a remote or a local lookup as currently you are doing a local lookup and not a remote lookup...

Comment: sorry for asking unclearly . I want to a local lookup.